# The view 'SummaryReport' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 3 project in one solution:

1. Library -> Console App
2. Project1 -> MVC
3. Project2 -> MVC

`Project1` and `Project2` have similarly views, we called it `SummaryReport.cshtml` in folder `Monthly`. So the structure of `Project1` and `Project2` views is like this:

```
- Project1/Project2
  \--Views
  \---Monthly
  \----SummaryReport.cshtml
```

Then I have controller name `Monthly.cs` in both projects.

I plan to move controller `Monthly.cs` to a library project, so I can share `Monthly.cs` between project1 and project2. It's successfully for the controller. Btw, I share that with copy and paste as link to project1 or project2.

I want to copy the `SummaryReport.cshtml`, too; first I put that file into `Library - Views - Monthly - SummaryReport.cshtml`, then I am doing the same thing when I create for controller, copy and paste as link that view to project1 and project2.

But I get some error:

> [InvalidOperationException: The view 'SummaryReport' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
> ~/Views/Monthly/SummaryReport.cshtml
> ~/Views/Monthly/SummaryReport.vbhtml
> ~/Views/Shared/SummaryReport.cshtml
> ~/Views/Shared/SummaryReport.vbhtml]
>
> System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) +511
> System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +143
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +91   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +32
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +46
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +426
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +172
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +158

What happen with this? How to fix this? I also have already add reference project1 to my Library project and set the dependencies similar. What is the best way to reusable view?

Thanks in advance.

I expecting the shared view is successfully

Update my `SummaryReport` function in `MonthlyController`:

```
public ActionResult SummaryReport()
{
    var model = db.Database.SqlQuery<MontlhySummary>("SELECT * FROM monthlySummary").ToList();

    ViewBag.Title = "Monthly Report";

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? or VSCode? Does this happen locally when you are debugging or only in production? Instead of copy & Pasting the view try to create a new file and paste the contents into the new file.

Comment: Im using Visual Studio. This happen when i debugging. For now the solution is i only can do with mklink in Windows for Views